# Location of the WPA_SUPPLICANT.conf file on Ubuntu Phone

Tags: wireless, ubuntu-touch

as mentioned i'm looking for the wpa_supplicant.conf file or similar on the ubuntu phone. The reason is, i'm trying to connect to a EAP protected network which the unity8 gui does not seem to support, so im trying to add it manually which should work since ubuntu does seem to use wpa_supplicant.

Q: Where does the Ubuntu Phone System store Wireless Network information for networks it knows?

thanks in advance!